# Getting a http 405 response by submitting a from using php curl

Tags: php, curl, uber-api

I am trying to create a uber user by submitting the data on thr form at :
        https://get.uber.com/new-signup/

My Code is :

```
<?php
function alpha($len) {
 $characters = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randstring = '';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++) {
        $randstring = $randstring.$characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $randstring;

}

function alpharnd() {

    return alpha(8)."-".alpha(4)."-".alpha(4)."-".alpha(4)."-".alpha(12);
}

$post_data['signup_form'] = 'web_signup_new';
$post_data['country_code'] = 'CA';
$post_data['language'] = 'en_US';
$post_data['client_id'] = '';
$post_data['signup_type'] = 'organic';
$post_data['signup_session_id'] = alpharnd();
$post_data['skip_signup_sms'] = 'True';

$post_data['first_name'] = 'Sanjay';
$post_data['last_name'] = 'Das';
$post_data['mobile_country'] = 'IN';
$post_data['mobile'] = '*****';
$post_data['email'] = '*****';
$post_data['password'] = '*****';
$post_data['promotion_code'] = '';


$url = 'http://get.uber.com/signup_submit/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);    // we don't need body
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "<hr>";
echo 'HTTP code: ' . $httpcode;
echo "<hr>";
print_r($info);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($post_data);
echo "<hr>";
?>
```

I am getting the following output :

```
HTTP code: 405
Array ( [url] => https://get.uber.com/signup_submit/ [content_type] => text/html [http_code] => 405 [header_size] => 540 [request_size] => 515 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 1 [total_time] => 1.849064 [namelookup_time] => 0.810126 [connect_time] => 1.065471 [pretransfer_time] => 1.590718 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 178 [speed_download] => 96 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => 178 [upload_content_length] => 0 [starttransfer_time] => 1.84903 [redirect_time] => 0.805986 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 104.36.192.180 [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 103.21.59.198 [local_port] => 46643 )
Array ( [signup_form] => web_signup_new [country_code] => CA [language] => en_US [client_id] => [signup_type] => organic [signup_session_id] => HIB7CN8M-2OK2-DJC-OTE1-3WZP3XXC03T [skip_signup_sms] => True [first_name] => Sanjay [last_name] => Das [mobile_country] => IN [mobile] => 8732311456 [email] => rohotgu1u789in@gmail.com [password] => ggg1234fgtrf [promotion_code] => )
```

Where i am doing wrong ??? I am getting the HTTP code: 405

Please advise....

Comment: 405 means that the method you're using (post) isn't allowed on that URL. Do you know if what you are trying to do actually works? I would be surprised if they didn't have some kind of CSRF or similar.

Comment: Not sure if that was a valid email/password you pasted, but if so, you'll want to change it immediately.

Comment: It's a safe bet that you can't just make up a random `signup_session_id` and hope it works.

Comment: I bet that `signup_session_id` is used to prevent CSRF. Read up on [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) and you will see why you probably can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The Form is submitted by POST only.. Please see this       <form id="signup-form" action="/signup_submit/" method="POST" autocomplete="on">

Comment: @AlexHowansky Its not login details in form.. Its signup form and i am giving a email and password in form.. just values in the code are marked as xxxxxxxxx

Comment: What you are trying to do is called CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) and any decent built site has protection against that. It might simply respond with a 405 if it detects that the request comes from somewhere else and contains an invalid signup_session_id.